How do I cite a newspaper comic strip in MLA style?
As part of an academic writing assignment, I've been asked to write an essay and to include MLA style citations in-line and in a "Works Cited" section at the end. This essay is an analysis of a story, and so the vast majority of references are to the story that the essay is about. However, I've also referred to a newspaper comic strip (Calvin & Hobbes for those curious) as a contrasting example, including direct quotations from the strip. Since I'm quoting directly, I need to cite the source, and since the citations need to be in MLA style, I need to cite the comic strip in MLA style.
Unfortunately, there's not much info out there about citing the funnies in academic writing.
Since newspaper comic strips appear in multiple papers at the same time, there's no one true original source that the strip appeared in, so I don't think it makes much sense to cite a specific newspaper - but that leaves me without a "container" for the strip. For the "Works Cited" section, my current best guess is something along the lines of "Watterson, Bill. "Calvin & Hobbes". Comic strip. Universal Syndicate, December 31, 1995. Print", based on the MLA guidelines available from Purdue, but I'd prefer something that directly addresses my specific use case rather than guessing.
As for the in-text citations, I obviously have to cite "Watterson", but what comes along with that? The MLA guidelines focus heavily on chapters and page numbers, neither of which is particulaly applicable to this case. My instinct would be to add the year of publication, i.e. "(Watterson, 1995)", but it doesn't seem like the year is a focus of MLA style at all.

My other thought was just to avoid the problem entirely, via putting a line such as "...in the final Calvin & Hobbes comic strip, published December 31, 1995, Bill Watterson uses..." before the quotations, but I'm not familiar enough with the MLA guidelines to say if that's a.) acceptable b.) the proper way to go about this.
I could just email my professor (and may well still do so), but in the interests of publicly available knowledge: How do I cite a specific newspaper comic strip in MLA style, both in-text and in a bibliography?

At least some of the calvin&hobbes comics are also available as books, which are easlity citeable. Have you looked into that?

I think it would be OK to cite one particular newspaper even if it appears in several. Does the MLA guide say how to cite newspaper articles? If so, I think you could just use that style. Also perhaps you could give a link like https://www.pressreader.com/usa/the-washington-post/20241125/page/27 (you might be able to log into this site through a local library or university library)

http://www.comicsresearch.org/CAC/cite-em.html

School librarians get a thrill from supplying students with this type of information.

It is not relevant for your purposes that the comic strip you wish to cite has appeared in multiple different places including, perhaps, in a comic collection or in multiple different syndicated newspapers. Citations are not indicators of "The One True Source" (see, for example, section 8.1 of the APA Publication Manual). Their purpose is simpler; namely, to allow a reader to verify that the material cited is of the nature (content, form, etc) as the citer implies, and to indicate the material that you have read/seen. Hence you need only focus on a single place you have seen the strip and where you know the comic strip can be found.
If you accessed the particular Calvin and Hobbes cartoon in a printed collection or book, you would cite it as you would a chapter or section in a book:
Works Cited Entry: Watterson, Bill. “Comic Title or Description of the Strip.” Calvin and Hobbes, Andrews McMeel Publishing, Year, page number(s).
Fictitious example: Watterson, Bill. “Snowmen striking.” The Calvin and Hobbes One Hundred and Tenth Anniversary Book, Future Publishing, 1995, p. 42.
In-Text Citation: (Watterson 42)
If you are citing a strip as published in a newspaper:
Works Cited Entry: Watterson, Bill. “Comic Title or Description of the Strip.” Newspaper Name, Date, page number(s).
Fictitious example: Watterson, Bill. “Snowmen melting.” The Reindeer Post, 24 Dec. 1995, p. D12.
In-Text Citation: (Watterson D12)
If you have the option of either citing a website where the cartoon has appeared, or citing a hardcopy publication, I would choose the hardcopy. It might be harder for a reader to get hold of but the citation is likely to be meaningful well beyond the lifetime of a typical webpage.

Could you say what this answer is based on: official MLA information, guidance from some respected third party, your experience of what other authors do, or just what you personally think is logical?

Citations are not indicators of "The One True Source". Actually they usually are, e.g. with journal papers. With comic strips I agree it is different.

Their purpose is simpler; namely, to allow a reader to verify that the material cited is of the nature (content, form, etc) as the citer implies. No, it is to identify the source and allow the reader to do whatever they want with that information. Unfortunately, citations often don't clearly imply anything specific about the content of the material cited. It could be evidence to back up a statement, or an example of similar research, or something else.
